# How to Install Homebrew on Windows WSL Ubuntu, and fix "zsh: brew command not found" error

Tags: windows, homebrew, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

**Installation was a series of 5 simple steps:**

first, install homebrew itself from command in the [home page](https://brew.sh/):

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

After that, following instructions [in this page](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux), and changing `~/.bash_profile` to `~/.profile` as I am using Ubuntu as my wsl distro, i had to give these commands:

```
test -d ~/.linuxbrew && eval $(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
test -d /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew && eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
test -r ~/.profile && echo "eval \$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)" >>~/.profile
echo "eval \$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)" >>~/.profile
```

But now, when I try to run brew, I get `command not found` error.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In a wsl environment, brew is installed at location: `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/` which is **not** part of the path.

So we simply need to add that to path, and it works. I am using zsh as my shell, so I add these lines to my `~/.zshrc` file (in ubuntu file system) :

```
export BREW_HOME="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:$BREW_HOME"
```

Comment: This is the right one. Saved me the headache.

Answer (score 0):

if you happen to need to share your `.zshrc` across different OS, you can do some OS check in your `zshrc` file to see if it is macOS or linux/wsl:

```bash
case `uname` in
  Linux)
    ## add brew home to PATH in linux/WSL
    brew_home=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew
    if [ -d "${brew_home}" ]; then
      export PATH=${brew_home}/bin:$PATH
    fi

    javac_loc=/usr/bin/javac
    if [ -x "$javac_loc" ]; then
      export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f $(dirname $(readlink -f $javac_loc)))
    fi
  ;;
  Darwin)
    ## Do macOS thing...
    export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
  ;;
esac
```